# Visual Studio Code autosave when run code from Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code to use with Unity. Everything is great except for one small annoyance. When I edit my source code in Code and switch to Unity to run my game, the code is not automatically saved. I have to manually save the VS Code before switching.

I checked settings, but could not find anything. Is there anyway to effect this?

Comment: Not sure if possible in VS code, but building the program (usually `ctrl+b`) saves all source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: AutoSave]

This works fine for me, is this option visible to you?